# This is my idea on roll dice in functions, is it good?

Tags: arrays, c, function

Write a code for a game called double dices.

Each player takes their turn to roll two dices. (So, player one rolls 2 dices then player 2 rolls two dices). To roll a dice player 1 presses the number 1 and player 2 presses the number 2. The dice numbers are from 1 to 6. If the sum of the two dices = 12 then that player is the winner
If the sum of the two dices = 10 the player gets a golden token 2 golden tokens without the any player reaching sum 12 will automatically make the player the winner. Create a module that checks for the winner and output who the winner is.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#define Roll 2

// Function Declarition
void winner(int [], int []);

int main()
{
    int player1[Roll], player2[Roll], p1sum=0, p2sum=0;
    int i, j, dice, p1[0], p2[0];
    
    srand(time(0));
    
    // Prompts Player 1 to press enter.
    printf("\n  Player 1: Press Enter to roll your dice!!!\n");
    getc(stdin);// collects the propmt.
    
    // 
    for(i = 0; i < Roll; i++)
    {
        player1[i] = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        p1sum += player1[i];
    }
    printf("\t Player 1 rolled %d dice\n\t The Sum of the two rolls are: %d\n", i + 0, p1sum);
    
    printf("\n  Player 2: Press Enter to roll your dice!!!\n");
    getc(stdin);
    for(j = 0; j < Roll; j++)
    {
        player2[j] = (rand() % 6) + 1;
        p2sum += player2[j];
    }
    printf("\t Player 2 rolled %d dice\n\t The Sum of the two rolls are: %d\n", j + 0, p2sum);
    
    // initializing an array to variable p1sum.
    
    
    // Function Call.
    winner(p1sum, p2sum);
    
    return 0;
}



void winner(int p1sum [], int p2sum [])
{
    int x, w;
    //int p1sum = p1[0];
    //int p2sum = p2[0];
    
    p1sum[0];
    p2sum[0];
    
    for (w=0; w < Roll; w++)
    {
        if (p1sum == 12)
        {
            printf("\nPlayer 1, You've Won the prize");
        }
        else if (p2sum == 12)
        {
            printf("\nPlayer 2, You've Won the prize");
        }
        else if (p1sum == 10)
        {
            printf("\nPlayer 1 gets a golden token");
        }
        else if (p2sum == 10)
        {
            printf("\nPlayer 2 gets a golden token");
        }
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Make a method for rolling dice  `int rollDice(int rollCount)`. When both player get 12 why 1 is winner? isn't it a tie? same goes for 10.

Comment: oh because the first one to 12 wins, the players get to roll two times and I realize there's going to be a possibility of a tie

Comment: I had an idea on how to roll back but don't know the syntax.

Comment: You can tell if it's good by running it and seeing if it works. *Is it good?* is not a question we can answer here. This site is for questions about **specific problems** you're having with code or a programming tool. *I wrote this code. Is it good?* is not a question about a problem.

Comment: You can use this stackexchange site - https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ for code reviews. [SO] can help when you are stuck at programming. But this site probably has better code reviewers.

Answer (score 0):

make methods like:

```
int rollDice(int rollCount);
boolean findWinner(int score1, int score2);
```

Then code something like this:

```
int sum1,sum2;
do {
   sum1 = rollDice(2);
   sum2 = rollDice(2);
}while(!findWinner(sum1, sum2))
```

Comment: oh I get what you saying, thanks for the tip.

Comment: IMO, the winner cannot be boolean. There are 3 possibilities - player 1 wins, player 2 wins, draw.